# How to use ipinfo.io's json for php

Tags: php, json, ip

How can we use this json for php?

```
$ curl ipinfo.io
{
"ip": "178.78.135.10",
"hostname": "No Hostname",
"city": null,
"region": null,
"country": "AM",
"loc": "40.0000,45.0000",
"org": "AS49363 Orange Armenia CJSC"
}
```

I've found this at here : http://ipinfo.io/

Answer (score 0):

Use file_get_contents to fetch the data and json_decode to turn it into php.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/"));
print_r($data); /* print results */
```

Comment: Im getting this: stdClass Object ( [ip] => 178.78.135.10 [hostname] => No Hostname [city] => [region] => [country] => AM [loc] => 40.0000,45.0000 [org] => AS49363 Orange Armenia CJSC )

Comment: Yes, that's what you should get. What else do you want to do with it?

Comment: I need to array them? like i want it to be "Your IP: 178.78.135.10 "

Comment: @EddHakobyan This will get your **server's** IP address, not the **user**.

Comment: Exactly I want to get the country info "Your Country: Armenia" i don't need the ip http://eddhakobyan.esy.es/ipinfo/#

Comment: @ethan476 i got this error: PHP Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\prev20~.php on line 12 PHP Stack trace: PHP 1. {main}() C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\prev20~.php:0

Answer (score 0):

Using this server-side (i.e. PHP) will display **your server's** IP and information, not the user's.

If you want information on the **user**, you need to use JavaScript to implement [their JSONP API](http://ipinfo.io/developers) to have the user's browser call the API and return info on the user's IP.

Alternatively, you need to call their API for the user's IP:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}/json"));
```